# Observable.never() keep emitting values

Tags: rxjs

I have the following Observable that I subscribe to:

```
Observable
      .interval(2000)
      .withLatestFrom(this.formObservable.map(x => x.data))
      .map(x => shouldThisRun ? x[1] : Observable.never())
      .do(console.log)
      .subscribe()
```

When I change the `shouldThisRun` value to `false`, the `Observable` emits the following in the console:

```
23:09:03.967 Subscriber.js:247 NeverObservable {_isScalar: false}
23:09:05.970 Subscriber.js:247 NeverObservable {_isScalar: false}
23:09:07.973 Subscriber.js:247 NeverObservable {_isScalar: false}
23:09:09.977 Subscriber.js:247 NeverObservable {_isScalar: false}
23:09:11.980 Subscriber.js:247 NeverObservable {_isScalar: false}
```

I don't want it to emit anything. I don't understand why it doesn't stop emitting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mapping an Observable into an Observable of Observable. The outer observable keeps emitting and that is what you're subscribing to. What you really want is to continually switch to the newest inner each time the outer emits (switch meaning: subscribe the new and unsubscribe the old). That is 
what switchMap does for you. Look at a marble diagram of switchMap to get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I had to change `x[1]` to `Observable.of(x[1])` as well otherwise it throws an error.